# Java Swing pack method not working as expected

Tags: java, swing, jframe

I am trying to create a GUI using Java Swing, and am having a problem using the `pack()` method. As you can see, I create and add all of the elements to the frame in the `createTitleText()`  method and the `createBoxes()` method. Only after those two methods are called do I call the `pack()` method, yet when I run the program, I get a small GUI with the close and minimize buttons. But if I expand it, it shows me the proper layout.

The only cause for such a problem that I have found online would be that I call `pack()` before adding all of my elements to the frame, but that is not the case. How can I fix this?

By the way, if it wasn't clear, I am trying to not use the `setSize()` method on the frame, and make it so that the frame's size fits the contents of the elements added to it.

```java
import javax.swing.*;
import java.awt.*;

public class Frame extends JFrame {

    private LetterBox[][] boxes;

    public Frame() {
        boxes = new LetterBox[6][5];

        // frame styling
        setTitle("My Frame");
        getContentPane().setBackground(new Color(0x121213));

        createTitleText();
        createBoxes();

        // boilerplate frame configuration
        setLayout(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        setVisible(true);
        pack();
    }

    public void createTitleText() {
        JLabel label = new JLabel("Test");

        label.setHorizontalTextPosition(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalTextPosition(JLabel.TOP);

        label.setHorizontalAlignment(JLabel.CENTER);
        label.setVerticalAlignment(JLabel.TOP);

        label.setBounds(0, 0, 400, 100);

        label.setForeground(Color.WHITE);
        label.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 36));

        add(label);
    }

    public void createBoxes() {
        for (int r = 0; r < 6; r++) {
            for (int c = 0; c < 5; c++) {
                LetterBox box = new LetterBox();
                boxes[r][c] = box;
                box.setLetter(r + " " + c);
                add(box.getBox()); // box.getBox() returns a JLabel
            }
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new Frame();
    }

}
```

Comment: **Don't use a null layout**. Swing was designed to be used with layout managers. The pack() method will invoke the layout managers of all the panels. Since you don't use layout managers the pack() does nothing. Since  you have row/column logic I would guess you should be using the `GridLayout`.

Comment: Consider using [layout managers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html). Also consider posting a [mcve] so I can reproduce your problem and try to find a solution.

Comment: Also, call pack() before you make the window visible.